# Time Varying Transfer Function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a discrete transfer function whose numerator and denominator are coming from an input port. At every sample time these numerator and denominator vectors change.

E.g.

@ t == 0

```
den == [1 0 -1]
```

@ t == 1

```
den == [1 0 0 -1]
```

What do I have to do in order for the transfer function to work with this?

I have tried:

1. Having a variable length signal.

SIMULINK did not like this and refused to run, complaining that the discrete transfer function block could not handle variable sized input.

2. Padding the vector with many leading zeros

This led to periodic spikes in the signal. Additionally, Simulink does not let you do this if you enter the values by hand, rather than as an input, so I don't think this is the way to do it either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How often will the denominator (or any other filter parameter) change? Will they be changing with every change of `t`, or will they alternate, change periodically, or change aperiodically? It's not surprising it doesn't work out of the box, as a lot of built-in MATLAB/SIMULINK functions assume time invariance.

Comment: @fiveclubs. They won't be changing every time step. They will change every few seconds (~ 5-15 seconds), frequency is not constant as it will be event driven.

Comment: Build your transfer function with single integrator and gain blocks and include event-drvien switches inbetween.

Comment: @thewaywewalk. I'm not entirely sure I get what you mean. Could you please expand a little?

Comment: Every transfer function is composed of integrators and differentiators, with a single gain each. So try to break down your transfer functions in as many single blocks as possible. The use of integrators is prefered. That way you can control every single gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved trivially with a single Simulink [S-Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/s-function-examples.html) file `sfuntvf.m`, like this.

In there, a custom fixed vector state with `y` and `u`s history is saved, and the time varying part is simply applied over the time history (depicted in cyan and yellow); here a FIR Filter with a random order (depicted in magenta).

Other build-in implementations shall consider the sucessive initial conditions between calls, and require the verification of the initial condition structure. The shown implementation is the easiest to deploy and understand.

The `A` and `B` vectors can be modified accordingly.

```
function [sys,x0,str,ts] = sfuntvf(t,x,u,flag)
N=20;
n=randi(N-2)+1;
A=[1;zeros(N-1,1)];
B=[1/n*ones(n,1);zeros(N-n,1)];
switch flag,
  case 0, [sys,x0,str,ts] = mdlInitializeSizes(N);
  case 2, sys = mdlUpdate(t,x,u,N,A,B); 
  case 3, sys = mdlOutputs(t,x,u,N,n);
  case 9, sys = []; 
  otherwise DAStudio.error('Simulink:blocks:unhandledFlag',num2str(flag));
end

function [sys,x0,str,ts] = mdlInitializeSizes(N)
sizes = simsizes;
sizes.NumContStates  = 0;
sizes.NumDiscStates  = 2*N;
sizes.NumOutputs     = 2;
sizes.NumInputs      = 1;
sizes.DirFeedthrough = 0;
sizes.NumSampleTimes = 1;
sys = simsizes(sizes);

x0  = zeros(2*N,1);
str = [];
ts  = [1 0]; 

function sys = mdlUpdate(t,x,u,N,A,B)
un=x(1:N,1);
yn=x(N+1:2*N,1);
y=-A(2:end)'*yn(2:end)+B'*un;
sys = [u;un(1:end-1);y;yn(1:end-1)];

function sys = mdlOutputs(t,x,u,N,n)
sys = [x(N+1);n];
```

[image: Model]
[image: Plot]